# indexを表示したいが配列に格納されているデータが表示される

Tags: c++

https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc068/tasks/abc068_b

下記の抜粋コードの部分で，maxにindexを格納して表示したいのですが，表示されるのがindexではなく配列に格納したデータが表示されてしまいます。
どのように修正を行ったらindexが表示されるのでしょうか。

Paiza.ioでCppを使用しています。

```
テスト値
入力：100
出力：64

※現在は8が出力されている
```

```
～～～～～～抜粋～～～～～～～

    int max = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (max < data[j]) max = j;
    }

    cout << max << endl;

    return 0;
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int getDivisionCount(int i) {
    int count = 0;
    while (i % 2 == 0) {
        i /= 2;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    int data[100];
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        data[i] = getDivisionCount(i);
    }
    
    int max = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (max < data[j]) max = j;
    }
    
    cout << max << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if (max < data[j]) max = j;

`max` を何の値を扱うための変数だと想定しているのですか？

`data[j]` と比較しているところを見ると，`max` はデータ値を扱うためのものと見えるが，
代入されているのは `j` であり，データ値ではなくindexである
……というところで，明らかに変です．

データ値たるべきなのかindexたるべきなのか，どちらの想定なのか知りませんが，想定通りの対象を扱うようにすればよいでしょう．
別の物を扱いたいなら別途それ用の変数を設けてみてはどうですか？

Comment: ……というわけで，変数名を例えば `max_data_value` だとか `max_index` だとか，何かもっと「何を入れる用なのか」がわかるように付け直してみたりすれば，間違いが浮き彫りになるのではないでしょうか．

Comment: ご指摘かつアドバイスありがとうございます。   
アドバイス通り変数名を具体的にして修正を行ったところ明らかにおかしいコードの記載をしていることに気が付けました。  
その後，無事ACしました。  
変数名を軽視してた部分があったので，とても重要なことを学べた気がします。  
ありがとうございました。